# How do I make the body of a Dialog transparent?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to hide the background dialog box while the inner content will not.

I cannot just set opacity to 0 because the children node will also be hidden:

```
<Dialog
    title="Dialog With Actions"
    actions={actions}
    modal={no}
    open={@state.open}
    onRequestClose={=> @setState open: no}
    contentStyle={opacity: '0'}
  >
    <CircularProgress style={
      position: 'fixed'
      top: '40%'
      left: '48%'
    }/>
</Dialog>
```

Comment: Did you try `backgroundColor: 'transparent',`?

Answer (score 0):

Just use RGBA values, which doesn't persist to children like:

`background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0)`

Comment: can you get a working copy up somewhere so we can visually see what your trying to accomplish?

Comment: ＠finalfreq This would be it https://github.com/enu-kuro/React-Loader-Overlay-Sample